# Chromedriver error: [Errno13] Permission denied 'chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, flask

I have an app with Flask that uses Selenium with a Chrome webdriver to scrape the web. It works flawlessly when I'm testing it locally. However, I tried deploying to Heroku and I keep getting the following two errors:

```
PermissionError: [Errno13] Permission denied 'chromedriver/chromedriver.exe' 

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

This is the section of my code where I refer to the chromedriver.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://sis.pleasantonusd.net/StudentPortal')
```

The file `chromedriver.exe` is in the folder `chromedriver`, which is level with the file GradeScraper.py (the file with the Selenium code). Here is the directory structure:

```
QC-Scraper
|- app.py
|- GradeScraper.py
|- Procfile
|- requirements.txt
|- README.md
|- chromedriver
    |- chromedriver.exe
|- templates
    |- grades.html
```

In the structure, `app.py` is the main Flask app, where the `app.run()` function is called. `GradeScraper.py` is the part with the actual scraping code, and it is imported into `app.py`.
I'll try my best to provide any extra information necessary. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I changed the Windows chromedriver to a Linux chromedriver and deployed it, the error still persists.

EDIT2: I also added a release command in the procfile, `chmod +x chromedriver/chromedriver`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What are the access rights of `chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't understand.

Comment: If it helps at all, I'm an admin on my computer.

Comment: that does not matter, it depends on as what user you are running the program. Typically daemons for instance run on a different user, to prevent a hacker that has achieved access to a certain file, to access al files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that `chromedriver.exe` doesn't have the executable bit set.

But I don't think that matters since you are trying to run a Windows program (.exe) on an Linux machine which is what Heroku is.

Comment: So, should I download some sort of chromedriver for linux?

Comment: I downloaded the Linux chromedriver and added it, the error still persists. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: did you figure this out , I'm having the same issue